# Javascript returns and calling another function question

Tags: javascript, formatting, currency

I need to write code to
Use a prompt() to gather an initial dollar amount from the user and then pass that value into a calculation function(already created) called calculation(). Then I need to take the return of that function and pass it to the current function. The returned, properly formatted value (the calculation function formats numbers), should appear in an alert() box.

Function format(){
cashAmount = Number(prompt("Enter amount to be formatted"));

}

This is as far as I've gotten. I'm confused at the function returning another function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these lines.

If the boolean parameter separatedByComma is true we ara going to use the Number method toLocalString("en-US") return the number separated by commas. If the parameter is false it's return a foramted number without commas "$533535".

```
const ashAmount = Number(prompt("Enter amount to be formatted"));

function format(ashAmount, separatedByComma) {
  return separatedByComma
    ? `$${ashAmount.toLocaleString("en-US")}`
    : `$${ashAmount}`;
}

format(ashAmount, true);
```

Comment: I already have a calculation function that formats the number in a specific way. What I need to do is pass the user entered number into my calculation function. Then Take the return of that function and pass it to this new format() function. Could you help with that?